# expected primary-expression before '%' token & 'else' without a previous 'if'

Tags: c++

novice programmer here learning for my Associates in Computer Science
I'm having a problem with my current assignment and I'm trying to figure out where my 2 syntax errors are. I've been looking at similar assignments that I've done but to no avail I can't find the problem I'm having.

I'm getting the following errors on these 2 lines:

> 'else' without a previous 'if' @ "else if (num >= 1 && num <= 50 && num % 2 == 0) //check for EVEN number between 1 and 50"
>
> expected primary-expression before '%' token @ "else if (num > 50 %% num <= 100 && num % 10 == 0) // Check for MULTIPLE OF 10 between 51 and 100"

```
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    cout << "Jon Grezda CS 12 Wednesday 6-8pm" << endl;
    cout << "Assignment #9" << endl;

    int num;
//num - Number input

    cout << "Please enter a whole number between the numbers 1-100." << endl;
    cin >> num;     //Is the number in the right range?

    if (num < 1 || num > 100) //INVALID Number, Terminate program

        cout << "INVALID NUMBER, rerun program and please try again" << endl;
    cout << "Program Terminated";

    else if (num >= 1 && num <= 50 && num % 2 == 0) //check for EVEN number between 1 and 50

        cout << "The number " << num << " is an EVEN number";

    else if (num >= 1 && num <= 50 && num % 2 == 1) //check for ODD number between 1 and 50

        cout << "The number " << num << " is an ODD number";

    else if (num > 50 % % num <= 100 && num % 10 == 0) // Check for MULTIPLE OF 10 between 51 and 100

        cout << "The number " << num << "is A MULTIPLE OF 10";

    else // Check for NOT A MULTIPLE OF 10 between 51 and 100
        cout << "The number " << num << "is NOT A  MULTIPLE OF 10";

}
```

Comment: why there is `%%` in your last else if

Comment: oh my god Lmao... I'm so embarrassed I didn't notice that

Answer (score 3):

You have two statements between the `if` and the `else`.  You need to use curly brackets `{ }` to group those statements into one.

```
if (num < 1 || num > 100) //INVALID Number, Terminate program
{
    cout<<"INVALID NUMBER, rerun program and please try again"<<endl;
    cout<<"Program Terminated";
}
else if (num >= 1 && num <= 50 && num % 2 == 0) //check for EVEN number between 1 and 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Add grouping as @1201ProgramAlarm suggested and then
replace "%%" with '&&" in following condition

```
if (num > 50 %% num <= 100 && num % 10 == 0) // Check for MULTIPLE OF 10 between 51 and 100
```

Complete Code:

```
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    cout << "Jon Grezda CS 12 Wednesday 6-8pm" << endl;
    cout << "Assignment #9" << endl;

    int num;
    //num - Number input

    cout << "Please enter a whole number between the numbers 1-100." << endl;
    cin >> num;     //Is the number in the right range?

    if (num < 1 || num > 100) //INVALID Number, Terminate program
    {
        cout << "INVALID NUMBER, rerun program and please try again" << endl;
        cout << "Program Terminated";
    }        
    else if (num >= 1 && num <= 50 && num % 2 == 0) //check for EVEN number between 1 and 50
    {
        cout << "The number " << num << " is an EVEN number";
    }
    else if (num >= 1 && num <= 50 && num % 2 == 1) //check for ODD number between 1 and 50
    {
        cout << "The number " << num << " is an ODD number";
    }
    else if ((num > 50 && num <= 100) && num % 10 == 0) // Check for MULTIPLE OF 10 between 51 and 100
    {
        cout << "The number " << num << "is A MULTIPLE OF 10";
    }
    else // Check for NOT A MULTIPLE OF 10 between 51 and 100
    {
        cout << "The number " << num << "is NOT A  MULTIPLE OF 10";
    }

}
```